# How to download arbitrary files as part of a custom target with CMake?

Tags: cmake

CMake, through its [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/ExternalProject.html), makes it easy to download huge archives during a build, keeping repositories clean. As an example, I can have Eigen downloaded and unpacked like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    eigen
    URL http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.2.8.tar.bz2
    URL_HASH SHA512=53c27ba530c985dfef52188e03273eeef33abbc67e3f150cacd3371c8b9ddbd399228730595821c4c56c061d109cf509266c1dab2b8a7c730902cbd6fb18c100
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

I would like to be able to do the same for arbitrary files, in my case to download additional data for demonstration purposes. CMake does offer [`file(DOWNLOAD...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/file.html) for this purpose, and it works well enough, e.g.:

```
file(DOWNLOAD
    http://graphics.stanford.edu/pub/3Dscanrep/bunny.tar.gz
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo/bunny.tar.gz
    SHA512=59e7b43db838dbe6f02fda5e844d18e190d32d2ca1a83dc9f6b1aaed43e0340fc1e8ecabed6fffdac9f85bd34e7e93b5d8a17283d59ea3c14977a0372785d2bd
    SHOW_PROGRESS
)
add_custom_target(demo tar -xzf ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo/bunny.tar.gz -C ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/demo)
```

This downloads an archive, validates it and -- with `make demo` -- extracts it. However, the archive is downloaded every time CMake is run, not just once, and it does not depend on the target `demo` being invoked.

Can this somehow be achieved with CMake? I don't think that `ExternalData` will help, because I really just want to download arbitrary files from the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the archive is downloaded every time CMake is run, not just once, and it does not depend on the target demo being invoked.

No wonder why. You're not adding the target `eigen` or whatever as a dependency for `demo`.

So, something like following should work:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    bunny
    PREFIX "demo"
    URL http://graphics.stanford.edu/pub/3Dscanrep/bunny.tar.gz
    URL_HASH SHA512=59e7b43db838dbe6f02fda5e844d18e190d32d2ca1a83dc9f6b1aaed43e0340fc1e8ecabed6fffdac9f85bd34e7e93b5d8a17283d59ea3c14977a0372785d2bd
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

**NOTE:**

<s>Target produced by `ExternalProject_Add` extracts archives by default. And  You're downloading archive called `bunny.tar.gz` which contains another `src/bunny.tar.gz` bundled inside.</s>

**EDIT:**
If we're talking about newer-ish CMake (>=3.11) You should also take a look at [FetchContent()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) (official docs), which may take some burdens away as well.

Comment: Great, `ExternalProject` works well. It actually renders the custom target superfluous, as the archive is extracted automatically. One might want to move the resulting files around a bit, though.

Comment: Contrary to the note, the archive `bunny.tar.gz` does not contain another archive `src/bunny.tar.gz` bundled inside. CMake just seems to keep a copy around at that location.

Comment: @Shedeki, oh, sorry then. Some kind of fancy caching probably is messing things up.... Btw, by default it also tries to build provided external project. Unless explicitly stated not to.

Comment: Why not using simply `file(DOWNLOAD url)` ?

Comment: Well, ExternalProject takes away the need for extra `custom_target()` and manual extraction.