# CMAKE CGAL ExternalProject_Add does not download the main dependency

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

The CMake command below downloads CGAL from github:
https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/v5.4.1

It downloads the source files but it does not download
**GMP and MPFR libraries, for Windows 64bits** as is seen in release structure.

**Question** How you would include these two compiled libraries as part of this command?

```
ExternalProject_Add(cgal
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/CGAL/cgal.git
  GIT_TAG v5.4.1
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)
```

I tried @Tsyvarev suggestion but it is installed in cgal_dependencies-prefix folder not in cgal folder :

```
ExternalProject_Add(cgal_dependencies
  URL https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/download/v5.4.1/CGAL-5.4.1-win64-auxiliary-libraries-gmp-mpfr.zip
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Comment: As currently writtinen, the code clones the **repository** https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/tree/v5.4.1, not the **archives** from the page https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/v5.4.1. For download and extract the archive, use `URL` option of the `ExternalProject_Add`. Note, that single `ExternalProject_Add` call may download only a single file or repository. If you want to download two files, you need to use two `ExternalProject_Add` calls. Do not forget to adjust dependencies between those calls (via `add_dependencies`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do not know what you mean, because you do not show the full code as an answer. I updated my question that shows that your suggestion gives me an error.

Comment: Looks like the archive you download doesn't contain a CMake or other project which needs to be configured or build. In that case you need to disable configuration and build step in `ExternalProject_Add`, like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024563/3440745).

Comment: This works thank you (2x updated answer).
But I have no knowledge how to use **add_dependencies** since it is unzipped in whatever directory...

Comment: According to your question post, your problem is not about dependencies but about **directory** where additional libraries are extracted. But why the directory is important for you? Note, that "release structure" as shown in https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/v5.4.1 is just a **list of archives**. It has nothing common with the directories where these archives should be extracted.

Comment: True. The problem is that I do not know right now how to link these two archives to one .exe project (beginner in CMake). The first repository is **header-only** library and the second link are just **2-dlls**. How you would refence the paths of these folders to the executable?

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add` unpack files into its source directory. Using `SOURCE_DIR` option you could specify exact directory which should be used as a source one. Alternatively, you may allow `ExternalProject_Add` to automatically select the directory, but later extract it using [ExternalProject_Get_Property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_get_property) function.