# CMAKE installs always to default directory even after I set -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using `ExternalProject_Add` command to download a zip file, but directory of download files are always the same build/cgal_dependencies-prefix.

My cmake code is below, it should be build/install but any change remains the same build/cgal_dependencies-prefix.

**question** how can I change the default installation directory?

```
#PROJECT INTIALIZATION
########################################################################
project(superbuild LANGUAGES CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

set(
  CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install"
  CACHE STRING
  "Final install location."
)

ExternalProject_Add(cgal_dependencies
  URL https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/download/v5.4.1/CGAL-5.4.1-win64-auxiliary-libraries-gmp-mpfr.zip
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" #do not configure
  BUILD_COMMAND "" #do not buld
  INSTALL_COMMAND "" #installer for now is empty
)
```

Comment: Your `ExternalProject_Add` neither configures nor builds nor installs: this is explicitly written in the comments to your code. What a reason to specify CMAKE_ARGS for it? As I noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72660230/cmake-cgal-externalproject-add-does-not-download-the-main-dependency#comment128349934_72660230) to your previous question, the directory for the unpacked files can be specified with `SOURCE_DIR` option. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, no change. I tried  **SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install"** and **INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install"**

Should I remove some of arguments?

Comment: It is installed in **C:\Program Files (x86)\superbuild**
I have no idea why it is this directory...

Comment: I changed the directory to this which points to the folder build/bin **SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal_dependencies"**

Comment: What **exactly** is installed into `C:\Program Files (x86)\superbuild` directory? It is definitely not files unpacked from `cgal_dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

This is the build/install/libraryname directory

```
SOURCE_DIR   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal_dependencies"
```

This is the C:/Program Files (x86)/sortdemo/install/libraryname directory

```
 SOURCE_DIR   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/install/cgal_dependencies"
```

For some reason the default locations is C:/Program Files (x86) not C:/Program Files